# Notification to others on birthday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to send notification mail to others whose birthday is not today.
 I have used code to find out people having birthday today...

Code for controller:

```
@people = Person.find(:all, :conditions => ["DAY(date) = ? AND MONTH(date) = ?", Date.today.day, Date.today.month])
```

Now, how do I modify it to get people other than birthday person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely it should be:

```
@people = Person.where('DAY(date) <> ? AND MONTH(date) <> ?', Date.today.day, Date.today.month)
```

Using OR it will exclude people from other months where the day is today and from other days of the current month.

Answer (score 1):

`@people = Person.where('DAY(date) <> ? OR MONTH(date) <> ?', Date.today.day, Date.today.month)`

Answer (score 0):

```
@people = Person.where("extract(month from date) != ? AND extract(day from date) != ?", Date.today.month, Date.today.day)
```